# Сравнение массивов используя регулярные выражения

Tags: java, массивы, регулярные-выражения

Есть два массива, надо найти такие слова в первом массиве, которых нет во втором, используя регулярные выражения.

Comment: Что не получается? Как вообще предполагается использовать регулярные выражения в этой задаче?

Comment: @yozh не совсем могу понять где их можно использовать, эти регулярные выражения, ну насколько я понял, именно в сравнении элементов массива.

Comment: Учебное задание?

Comment: @ VladD да, 1 курс.

Comment: что массивы содержат? Каждый элемент является отдельным словом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данную задачу нельзя решить «красиво». Все таки регулярные выражения для этого не предназначены. Они служат для обработки строк, а не массивов.

```
String[] arr1 = {"word", "ford", "audi", "excel", "reno", "paint" };
String[] arr2 = {"ford", "reno", "audi"};
String allWords = "|"+ arrJoin( arr1, "||" ) + "|";
String regex = "\\|(?:(?:"+ arrJoin( arr2, ")|(?:" ) + "))\\|";
String diff = allWords.replaceAll( regex, "" ).replaceAll( "^\\||\\|$", "" );
String[] result = diff.split( "\\|+" );
System.out.println( arrJoin( new String[] {allWords, regex, diff, arrJoin( result, " " )}, "\n" ) );
```

Результат:

```
|word||ford||audi||excel||reno||paint|
\|(?:(?:ford)|(?:reno)|(?:audi))\|
word||excel||paint
word excel paint
```

Использована функция `arrJoin`

```
public static String arrJoin( Object[] arr, String separator ) {
    String result = "";
    for ( int i=0; i<arr.length; i++ ){
        result+= arr[i].toString();
        if ( i < arr.length-1) result+= separator;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Вместо нее сгодится например штатное средство Java8 `String.join` или любой другой аналог.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

1. Постройте регулярное выражение, проверяющее на наличие всех слов из первого массива (соедините их через `|`, не забудьте заэскейпить, что нужно)
2. Пройдитесь по второму массиву, выберите из него те элементы, которые не проходят через регулярку.

Изврат, да.

Код не привожу, т. к. учебное задание.

Comment: > проверяющее на наличие всех слов из первого массива.

не совсем понял, если честно.

Comment: Ну, допустим, слова в массива "мир", "труд" и "май". Тогда покатит регулярка `(мир)|(труд)|(май)`.

Comment: @ VladD но тогда регулярка, особо не имеет смысла, мне так кажется, разве нет?

Comment: @thundermind: Да. Но это ж учебное задание, бессмысленное и беспощадное.

Comment: @ VladD  у нас такой преподаватель, что за такое будет оценивать работу в минус баллы :(
а рационально ее не получится заюзать?

Comment: @thundermind: Ну, у меня лучше идей не возникло. Может у кого-то другого...

Comment: @thundermind: почему бессмысленно? Если [нет доступа к эффективной реализации  алгоритма Ахо-Корасика, то регулярные выражения это хороший *легко расширяемый* компромиссный по скорости вариант](http://goo.gl/xhNXNI) (например по сравнению с решением в лоб, где каждое слово в одном массиве сравнивается независимо с каждым элементом во втором массиве). Хотя если все элементы массивов являются отдельными словами (фразы, части слов не рассматриваем), то проще операции на множествами использовать, например: `{'мир', 'труд', 'май'} - {'май', 'мир'} == {'труд'}` (синтаксис Питона).

Comment: @jfs: Хм. Не думал о проблеме с этой стороны. +1.